# Configure Webpack externals for module.exports = require('react/lib/ReactDOM')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-dom

I have a library (ReactDOM) that's being required and assigned to `module.exports` and I'd like to configure webpack to register this export as an external. The [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) don't make it abundantly clear how I should do this...

> object: If an dependency matches exactly a property of the object, the
>   property value is used as dependency. The property value may contain a
>   dependency type prefixed and separated with a space...

The actual source file that I'd like to register as an external has the following assignment...

```
module.exports = require('react/lib/ReactDOM');
```

I tried the following configuration with no luck.

```
externals: {
    'react/lib/ReactDOM': 'commonjs ReactDOM'
}
```

*How can I configure webpack to register this require statement as an external dependency?*

---

I'm using React and ReactDOM ^15.1.0.

Comment: Just checking something... you're having to use an old version of React? `react-dom` is now its own npm package.

Comment: I have installed the packages separately (both `node_modules/react` and `node_modules/react-dom` exist), but `react-dom` has a `require` statement that pulls in the React library. Because I would like for webpack to build _without_ pulling in React, I'm trying to declare the `require` statement in react-dom (mentioned above) as an external.

Comment: Aaah. Interesting. No idea. Although I do notice in the docs, externals is an array with an object inside it, your config is just an object.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same, both seem to work, though.